# Vue Js Components : How To Decouple Data Sharing Between Multiple Component Instances

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, inertiajs

I Have a Side Project Which Require Me To **Repeat Multiple Component Multiple Time In The Same Page**

the functionality is used to get those multiples is, looping and importing like this to handle repeation

`<component :is="componentName" :id="uniqueId()"></component>`

the problem start appearing from this point;

> any action i've done on any element, affect all other element that have the same component type

for example, if I change a prop value of one component, it change on all components that have the same component type, not only the targeted one.

even `:id` doesn't help me with this, how can i handle it?

> components is globally registered

i'm trying to add unique identifier for every element even those with different component types, using `:id` and also `:key` but it doesn't help.

*I'm using Laravel/Inertia/vue stack.*

it's drag and drop functionality with some advanced feature, which user can change styling attributes

main item:

```json
{"id":"05adb562-e057-4f81-9396-0121b44f2349","list":1,"component_name":"TextInput","style":{"align":"center"}}
```

the drop code:

```js
const onDrop = (event, list) => {
    const itemId = event.dataTransfer.getData('itemID');
    const item = items.components.find((item) => item.id === itemId);
    const newItem = {
        id: uuidv4(),
        component: item,
        list: list,
        component_name : item.component_name,
        style: item.style
    };

    items.components.push(newItem);
}
```

and the styler and the changer is :

```js
const styler = reactive({
    item : null,
    isShown : false,
});

const changeAlign = (st, align) => {
    const curr =  items.components.find((item) => item.id === st.id);
    curr.style.align = align;
}
```

to show up a styler, we need to click on component

```js
<component @click="showStyler(item)"></component>
```

and event is made like:

```js
@click='changeAlign(styler.item, "left")'
```

Comment: Are you passing the same prop reference to each component? If so, try passing a *copy* of the prop

Comment: i think no. it's a drag and drop function, which takes a copy of item, but the props is created on the drop event, and not copied from the parent component, so I do exactly what you need me to try I think.

Comment: You are sharing some state between the component instances. Unfortunately, there there is not enough information to be able provide help beyond that.

Comment: @Daniel can you provide me which information is needed, to make question clearer.

Comment: @Daniel i've updated the question with code samples

Comment: where is `items` defined? looks like it's global

Comment: items is defined within the same file. a reactive function that hold all dragged and dropped components

Comment: When you make your newItem, try `component: { ...item }` (or another clone method) in its properties. Right now it is using the same actual `item` I believe

Comment: Just for understanding, I found, that how you use the naming of `item` and `component` is somehow misleading. You push an item into `items.components`? That is somehow really hard to understand. I would start to use better naming for the variables. Maybe that will bring some light into the actual issue. What is the difference between a `component` and an `item`?